# Swift Sort array based on another array

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

So I have 2 arrays

```
let knownOrder = ["Headache level", "Headache side", "Nausea", "Aura", "Phonophobia" ,"Photophobia"]

let tmpArray = ["Aura","Headache side","Photophobia"]
```

- Note - The tmpArray can include all or some of the 'knownOrder' array objects.

And now what i want to do is to sort the 'tmpArray' in order based on the 'knownOrder'.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter `knownOrder` to remove any element that is not in `tmpArray`:

```
let knownOrder = ["Headache level", "Headache side", "Nausea", "Aura", "Phonophobia" ,"Photophobia"]

let tmpArray = ["Aura","Headache side","Photophobia"]

let ordered = knownOrder.filter { tmpArray.contains($0) }
print(ordered)
```

> ["Headache side", "Aura", "Photophobia"]

Comment: I have to do the same thing. But I have an  array of objects. Any help on that.